# Java - Regular Expression - Replacing Address with asterisk's

Tags: java, regex

Trying to replace this string with asterisks.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Before: 
100 Pike St. Unit 104

Becomes:
100 Pi** St* Un** ***

- Also would have to include if it doesn't contain the unit number-

So for example:

Before: 
100 Pike St.

Becomes:
100 Pi** St*

I am using: this regular expression to check if there is more than 1 digit

> (?:\d.*?){1}
>
> String[] splitAddress = address.split("");
>
> ```
>     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d.*?){1}");
>     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(address);
>
>     boolean isMatched = matcher.matches();
>     System.out.println(isMatched);
> ```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: More than one digit is just `\\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, an expression similar to,

```
(?i)^(\\d+)\\s+(\\S{2}).*?\\s+St.*?(Unit\\s+\\d+)?$
```

might be OK to look into.

---

You'd be wanting to write an `if` statement for the third capturing group, which has the `Unit`. If that group wasn't empty, you'd be concatenating another `*` for that.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?i)^(\\d+)\\s+(\\S{2}).*?\\s+St.*?(Unit\\s+\\d+)?$";
        final String string = "100 Pike St. Unit 104\n"
             + "100 Pike St.\n"
             + "100 Pike and Salmon STREET Unit 104\n"
             + "100 Pike and Salmon ST.";
        final String subst = "$1 $2** St*";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println(result);


    }
}
```

#### Output

```
100 Pi** St*
100 Pi** St*
100 Pi** St*
100 Pi** St*
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zqIucm/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/zqIucm/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### Number of Asterisks

If the number of `*` would be an issue, then you'd likely want to capture everything, do some simple counting for that, with an expression similar to:

```
(?i)^(\d+)\s+(\S{2})(.*?)\s+St(.*?)\s*(Unit\s+\d+)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/VuK8Ny/1/)

#### Test 2

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "(?i)^(\\d+)\\s+(\\S{2})(.*?)\\s+St(.*?)\\s*(Unit\\s+\\d+)?$";
        final String string = "100 Pike St. Unit 104\n"
             + "100 Pike St.\n"
             + "100 Pike and Salmon STREET Unit 104\n"
             + "100 Pike and Salmon ST.";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

#### Output 2

```
Full match: 100 Pike St. Unit 104
Group 1: 100
Group 2: Pi
Group 3: ke
Group 4: .
Group 5: Unit 104
Full match: 100 Pike St.
Group 1: 100
Group 2: Pi
Group 3: ke
Group 4: .
Group 5: null
Full match: 100 Pike and Salmon STREET Unit 104
Group 1: 100
Group 2: Pi
Group 3: ke and Salmon
Group 4: REET
Group 5: Unit 104
Full match: 100 Pike and Salmon ST.
Group 1: 100
Group 2: Pi
Group 3: ke and Salmon
Group 4: .
Group 5: null
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]